Auth::user() / auth()->user(), undefined method 'update'
In my code am trying to update the information but I receive error as.
i have created a function to update data on logged in users but i am getting the error "undefined method 'update'" even after i changed it to save() method.

undefined method 'update'.
function updateProfil of the UserController.php

public function updateProfil(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->name = $request->name;
        if ($request->has('password') && $request->password != ""){
            if (Hash::check($request->old_password, $user->password)){
                if ($request->password == $request->password_confirmation){
                    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
            $file = $request->file('foto');
            $nama = 'logo-' . date('YmdHis') . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move(public_path('/img'), $nama);

            $user->foto = "/img/$nama";
        }

        $user->update();

        return response()->json($user, 200);
    }

can you please help me? I am trying to update the user data. Please help me understand the error and solve it.

Please share the full and exact error message you're facing, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

You can't use $user->update();. update() is used on query builder or Eloquent model instances only
Change
$user->update();

to this
$user->save();


FYK (Eloquent model)
$user = Auth::user();
$user->name = 'New Name';
$user->save();

or
$user = Auth::user();
$user->update([
    'name' => 'New Name',
]);


thanks but I still get the same problem after I changed it to save(). 'undefined method save'

check $user = Auth::user(); has any value

if I use $user = $request->user() is this ok?
